# I don't want Ms excel to scroll down by cell units

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, scrolling

When I scroll down (or up) in Ms Excel 2007, it scrolls down so that only whole cells (or at least it tries to do so) could be displayed next in that page. And it keeps jumping down one complete row at a time to maintain that function.

This could be useful in some cases, but when you have large cells (vertical wise), it could be really confusing when scrolling up or down.

I want to able to scroll down smoothly just like in any browser, or in the Windows Explorer. I don't care if cells (rows) are partially visible in my page.

How can I achieve this in Ms Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not have this functionality. So the only thing you can do is to vertically merge cells to get the same size, so that excel still thinks there are lots of rows, and thus the scrolling will work as you want.

So basically, what you'd get is this:

[image]

***Note:*** *The image above was taken using OpenOffice Calc, but I have sufficient knowledge of Microsoft Excel to know that this will work. Its just to illustrate what you'd get.*

Notice how column B has the cells still in tact.

Comment: I don't quite understand your approach. Do you mean move the contents of a single cell on multiple cells that are merged as one?

Comment: Yes exactly. Its the only way excel will understand it, because scrolling is tied to the size of a single row. You can still make the rows say 25% height of the entire screen and just merge a few together instead of doing it as I showed in my example though...

Comment: A possible solution, thank you very much. It won't work in all situations though. It's quite irritating that this is a limitation in Excel though !